# Returning List Based on Optional Query Parameters

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-rest

I have To Develop an endpoint like the question below asks

```
/GET Filter_Questions - Returns list of questions based on the combination of following
query parameters
  a. Input
    i. Companies - List of companies - Optional
    ii. Subtopics - List of subtopics - Optional
    iii. Likes - Questions with more votes than votes sent as input - Optional
    iv. Date - Questions asked after a given date - Optional
    v. Tags - List of tags - - Optional
  b. Output
    i. Question ID
    ii. Question Text
    iii. Companies - List of companies for which the question was asked
    iv. Likes - Number of likes of the question
    v. Answer - Answer with most likes for the given question
    vi. Tags - Tags associated with the given question
```

How Should i approach this question, The way i can do this is to fetch all questions in a list then make seperate lists for all of the Query Parameters,

If The User provides 3 parameters, then 3 lists will be made, then i will fetch the duplicates from the list and return that created list

But I feel there has to be a cleaner way of approaching this?

Comment: You should definitely do this in a single query, no need to filter on the Java side. As it stands the question is to broad. Take a look at JPA, Hibernate and Spring Data JPA documentation. Then code a subset of the problem, maybe with just one list for filtering. Than you'll be either able to solve your problem on your own, or ask a question that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the optional filtering with e.g. Spring Data Specifications. Create a custom specification class that adds joins and predicates based on the given filter values.

The Spring Data repository then accepts that Specification as parameter and uses an entity graph that fetches all the associations you mentioned or use a DTO projection to fetch only the relevant data.